# passive probes and accurate measurements

Tags: oscilloscope, accuracy

I have read somewhere that if we have a 100 MHz oscilliscope then we can measure only the waveform of 10 MHz accuratley with an error of 1%.

My question is that if passive probes are used then will the measurements will be totally accurate upto 100 MHz of 100 MHz oscilloscope with an error of 1% only.

**OR for the accurate meausrement till 100 MHz waveform I should must have a 500 MHz oscilliloscope with passive probes also?**

Comment: You should define **what** error you mean, relating to what **properties** of the 10 MHz waveform like frequency, amplitude. What shape is the waveform, a sinewave or something else. Next time you read something like that, investigate **why** that is so, what is causing the error. Understanding **what happens** is more useful than knowing only that statement. I mean, by itself knowing that using a 100 MHz scope for a 10 MHz signal gives 1% error is  not very useful knowledge, what is useful is to know **why** that is so.

Comment: What does the datasheet for your oscilloscope say?

Comment: Often some relative measurements are highly valuable. Oh, and the Ground Wire will set the ringing, hence long GND wires make the scope display unusable.

Answer (score 2):

The [rule of thumb](https://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/Tektronix12_things_to_consider1.pdf) is 5x for 2% down (plus whatever inaccuracy there is in the 'scope circuitry since you are talking about total measurement accuracy).

At the rated frequency for the 'scope + probe your signal will be reduced to 70% in voltage, so it's the -3dB or half-power point.

Note that is for **sine waves only**. If your signal is anything but a sine wave (perhaps + DC) you will need more bandwidth, if there are sharp edges and you want to see them accurately, **much** more bandwidth. Another rule of thumb is that the bandwidth in GHz is 0.35/RT, where RT is the rise time in nanoseconds. So a 100MHz square wave with rise time of 500ps has bandwidth of 700MHz, and if you really wanted to measure the rise time accurately you should have a 'scope bandwidth in the GHz. A 100MHz scope could show something like a reduced amplitude and distorted sine wave and meet specifications. What it actually shows depends on the scope design and any anti-aliasing filter they have implemented, assuming a digital scope.

Keep in mind that the probes may present significant loading on the source. Using 10x probes typically results in much better frequency response and much less loading at moderate frequencies, but the noise floor is going to be 10x worse.

Image from Tektronix link above.

[image]